# Cannot install openssl1.1.0 using make

Tags: linux, openssl

I run 
./config
make
make test 
and get some error
[image]

What can I do?

Comment: *"Enter image description"* is not a good problem statement. You need to provide the output of the command with the problem. Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0.tar.gz
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

To verify it is working:

`$ openssl version`